# No redirect to external PHP file on mail/form submit

Tags: php, forms, email, submit

I have a one page website - and I do not want my e-mail form to redirect itself to the external php file.

*On submit -* 
www.mywebsite.name/email.php 
will open.

But - I want it to remain on the current page. With a div box sliding in with confirmation that the e-mail has been sent.

That coding works fine - I can see it starts to display the box for a fraction of a second and then it redirects the browser to the external PHP file...

How can I prevent that redirect.

Comment: Some code would help..

Comment: form has an attribute defines it action leave action=""

Answer (score 0):

Be sure, that the action attribut in the form is defined

```
<from name="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">


</form>
```